# Como formatar um número utilizando "toFixed" apenas se não for inteiro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, números

Tenho uma função que me retorna um número, que pode ser inteiro, como: 440; ou pode ser quebrado, como 466.1638231521. Porém preciso ter uma maneira de, a partir da função, descobrir se o número é quebrado. Caso ele seja inteiro, irei deixar da maneira que está, caso contrário, irei formatar usando `toFixed(4)`.

```
function geraFrequenciaNota(semitons) {
  let divisor = (semitons / 12)
  let exponenciado = Math.pow(2, divisor)
  let multFreq = 440 * exponenciado
  return multFreq.toFixed(4)
}
```

Esse é meu código até o momento, o problema é que quando o número for Inteiro, por exemplo 440, quero que retorne 440, e não 440.0000.

Comment: A solução está nas perguntas indicadas acima no box azul (apesar de não ser 100% exatamente igual, basta adaptar): por exemplo, `multFreq.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 4})`, ou o equivalente com `Intl.NumberFormat` (leia as respostas que tem lá para mais detalhes)

Comment: Sei que vc queria usar `toFixed`, mas infelizmente ele não permite uma quantidade variável de casas decimais (a menos que vc use a solução abaixo - `if (Number.isInteger(x)) { formata sem casas decimais } else { usa toFixed }`). Mas eu ainda acho `toLocaleString` uma solução melhor

Comment: Tá tudo bem, criei uma If e acabou ficando tudo certo! Usei o isInteger para retornar true, e utilizar o toFixed apenas quando for false